# return 401 response from asp.net with iis hosting with windows auth enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

We have asp.net api hosted in iis with windows auth enabled and allow anonymous access.
Its seems that when I return 401 response from api, IIS intercept it and trying to negotiate with browser for windows auth without ending current "request-response" (in that moment in browser popups windows auhth window, asking for credentials). At first, I'm wonder what should happen next if i provide valid creds? In asp pipiline request already ended at this moment. And in second - is it possible for just return 401 to browser without iis intercept it? Maybe some options in config or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following methods to solve the problem:

- Open IIS and select the website (or directory) that is causing the
  401
- Open the “Authentication” property under the IIS header
- Click the “Windows Authentication” item and click Providers
- Change the order and put NTLM on top.

After the change open Command Prompt and do a iisreset /noforce.

Comment: sorry, no luck here (

Comment: Are there any related error messages in event viewer?